# If zookeeper leader process is killed, should all followers get exceptions and restart too?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm working on a project using Zookeeper 3.4.6, and am performing some failure mode testing. While doing so, I found (what I think is) unexpected behaviour.

Should followers restart if the leader Zookeeper process is killed?

**Environment:**

```
OS:        Windows Server 2008 R2 (hosted in a Tanuki Java service wrapper)
Zookeeper: 3.4.6
Java JDK:  1.7.0.210
```

**Tests:**

The test is to kill Zookeeper processes and make sure the cluster recovers.

If I kill a **non-leader** process, it restarts and rejoins the cluster without affecting other nodes.

If I kill the **leader** process, the leader **and followers** restart. This doesn't seem right, as there's a period of time where clients can't connect to **any** Zookeeper node.

I've tried both **TCP** and **UDP** communication settings, but both exhibit the same behaviour. UDP is twice as quick to recover though.

**Zookeeper settings**

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
minSessionTimeout=5000
maxSessionTimeout=120000
dataDir=C:\\ProgramData\\Saab OneView\\ZooKeeper\\zoo-data
clientPort=2181
leaderServes=yes
autopurge.purgeInterval=24

# IP addresses blanked out here
server.1=0.0.0.1:2888:3888
server.2=0.0.0.2:2888:3888
server.3=0.0.0.3:2888:3888
server.4=0.0.0.4:2888:3888
server.5=0.0.0.5:2888:3888

# This is for zookeeper->zookeeper communication
# I've tried both settings, UDP has faster recovery time
# 0 = UDP 
# 3 = TCP (default)
electionAlg=3
```

**Sample follower exception causing shutdown**

```
20160309 05:35:51.958Z 20160309 05:35:51.958 [myid:3] - WARN  [RecvWorker:4:QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker@780] - Connection broken for id 4, my id = 3, error = 
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:765)
20160309 05:35:51.959Z 20160309 05:35:51.959 [myid:3] - WARN  [RecvWorker:4:QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker@783] - Interrupting SendWorker
20160309 05:35:51.959Z 20160309 05:35:51.959 [myid:3] - WARN  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:Follower@89] - Exception when following the leader
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readInt(BinaryInputArchive.java:63)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPacket.deserialize(QuorumPacket.java:83)
    at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readRecord(BinaryInputArchive.java:103)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Learner.readPacket(Learner.java:153)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Follower.followLeader(Follower.java:85)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:786)
20160309 05:35:51.960Z 20160309 05:35:51.960 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:Follower@166] - shutdown called
java.lang.Exception: shutdown Follower
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Follower.shutdown(Follower.java:166)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:790)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [ZOOKEEPER-3478](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-3478) it is an expected behaviour:

> It is normal behaviour that all the followers shutdown during a leader election. Since there is no leader after a leader crash, the servers that used to be followers are not followers anymore. So the followers shutdown and go back to LOOKING state in order to find the new leader.